# Broken Signal Generators?

Tags: circuit-analysis

The AC signal generators in my university's laboratory are such that whenever I turn them on and connect them to a multimeter to read the input voltage, I notice that the input voltage changes as I change the AC signal frequency by turning the knob for the frequency. Is this supposed to happen? In our experiments, we are asked to do things like plot graphs showing how voltage across a capacitor/inductor changes with frequency, etc. But if you want to get the desired graph(linear/inverse proportional form) you'd have to assume that the input voltage is always constant, right? Or am I missing something? My professors won't say anything on this matter(they're not very responsible, I'm not really in a decent university) and some of my classmates claim that they fake the data, while other claim that they actually get the desired curves. I get weird results and I think the signal generators are to blame, but I'm not sure. So I need to know if this is normal for the input voltage to change with frequency(and if so, why?), and if so how does this not affect my experiment? And if it does, am I expected to use some sort of potential divider trick?

Comment: What kind of multimeter do you use? Many multimeters are only usable up to a certain frequency. Above this frequency the readout will drop significantly.

Comment: A digital one. Oh I didn't know that. So I should use an oscilloscope to check?

Comment: This could be the signal generator, it could be the meter, *or it could be the load*; **the best instrument to use would be a scope**.  Keep in mind different ways of measuring AC voltage: peak, peak to peak, RMS, etc.

Comment: Measure the voltage from the generator at each frequency you do a measurement then it doesn't matter if the voltage changes with frequency - provided the output is stable at each frequency.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't understand the load part. How can the load affect the input voltage?

Comment: A good signal generator will output the same amplitude across frequencies. It's called 'output' btw. So now you must tell this community exactly how you did your measurement.

Comment: By input voltage, do you mean the 120/240V AC from the mains? If _that_ is changing significantly, you have bigger problems than malfunctioning signal generators.

Comment: No thats not changing, I checked.

Comment: If a generator has say a 50-ohm output impedance, the voltage you see depends on the load, because the source impedance and the load form a complex voltage divider (ie, a voltage divider with an equation potentially involving complex numbers describing inductive and capacitive reactance, not just real resistance)

Comment: "A digital one" isn't of much use as a description.  Pretty much **all** multimeters are digital these days.  It would be of more use to name the brand and model of meter, and to give the frequency range of the signals you are generating.

Comment: Multimeters have a limited bandwidth.  Cheap ones will accurately measure AC voltage to just over line frequency.  Expensive ones may measure accurately up to many kiloherz.

Comment: Note that the readout of a multimeter not only depends on frequency, but on the shape of the waveform as well. I remember as student having to do an experiment measuring voltages of different wave forms with many types of meters and explain the results. Things like form factor and crest factor are relevant with respect to this. I explained the results because of frequency dependency (non sinusoidal wave forms have higher harmonics)